# is it possible to play h264-mpegts format in ios?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg2-ts

Server transcodes the video to the h264/aac, and send video data to client simultaneously. To play and save the video data at the same time, I use mpegts as the container format, but the problem is that ios MediaPlayer can not play mpegts file.

Google said that i can used ios-build of ffmpeg to do the task, but it seem to be an overkill. is there any other ways to play mpegts in iphone using just iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know much about ios but yes, you can play mp4(h264) videos in your ios device. i run my h264 video url to ios safari web browser, it detect the video and quicktime player start to play that video. so you can check this by entering video url (i.e:- http://yourserver.com/yourvideo.mp4) to your ios safari web browser.

NOTE :- your mp4 video should be of codec "h264". Use FFMPEG to convert videos in h264 codec

Comment: thanks, you're right, default media player in ios can play H264 videos. Those videos are usually formated as mpegps, but what i need is mpegts-h264.